# How to set a cookie for unique views for dynamic post_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this functionality where the post get visited then the id selected views are to views+1 I want that if the user has revisited or refreshed the same post_id page the view count wouldn't get updated and set cookie for each new post_id.

```
<?php 

class blogDetails{
    public $post_id;
    public $blog = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        
        $this->blog = generalOperations::getBlogPostDetails($post_id);

       

        $cache = ($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';


        if(!$cache){
            $view = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
            foreach($view as $res){
                foreach($res as $r){
                    $newviews = ++$r;
                    $new = generalOperations::viewsUpdatePostCount($newviews,$post_id);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
?>
```

I have tried this

```
$page_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


        if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){

        $_SESSION['id'] = session_id();

 
        $visit_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $view = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
            foreach($view as $res){
                foreach($res as $r){
                    $newviews = ++$r;
                    $new = generalOperations::viewsUpdatePostCount($newviews,$post_id);
                }
            }
        }else{

        $visit_id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $view = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
        }

this only increments the value of the post viewed first doesnt update the value if viewed any other post_id page.
```

I tried to pass a cookie post id but now the cookie is not getting set

```
 $cookie_name = "views";
        $cookie_value = "Postviews";
        
        if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+86400, "/index.php?blog-page=true&post_id=$post_id");
            $do = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
            $cache = ($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
            if(!$cache){
                foreach($do as $res){
                    foreach($res as $r){
                        $newviews = ++$r;
                        $new = generalOperations::viewsUpdatePostCount($newviews,$post_id);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            $view = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
        }
```

Comment: what if a user visits after sometime/some days ?

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878) - please explain what actual _problem_ you are having with this. Show what you tried.

Comment: if a user visits after a month it would be counted as a view @AqibJaved

Comment: This is what have I tried I have an idea in my mind that to save the post_id as a cookie for the user the above code only does it count a view when revisted not when refreshed. @CBroe

Comment: Don't just _talk_ about it, but _show us_ what you actually tried.

Comment: Check I have updated @CBroe

Comment: Of course you can not implement this by storing just _one_ ID value. You will need to store all the visited ones, in an array.

Comment: Why not get remote address of visitor and save in database then compare the IP before increment in visitor count ?

Comment: IP address if saved in the database won't be able to increment if the different user has the same IP  want to make a cookie if viewed by the same user it won't register a new view count but viewed from the other user different system count that as view count @AqibJaved

Comment: To get anything meaningful you would need to use a combination of cookies, sessions and IP address tracking. Even then, it would be relatively trivial to spam your post view counters but it would require a little more effort.

Comment: I tried this but now the cookie isn't getting set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  class blogDetails{
    public $post_id;
    public $blog = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $post_id = $_GET['post_id'];
        // For blog details
        $this->blog = generalOperations::getBlogPostDetails($post_id);
        
        // For view count
        $cookie_name = $post_id;
        $cookie_value = "Postviews";
        $path = "index.php?blog-page=true&post_id=$post_id";
        
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+(86400), $path);
        

        if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
            $do = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
                foreach($do as $res){
                    foreach($res as $r){
                        $newviews = ++$r;
                        $new = generalOperations::viewsUpdatePostCount($newviews,$post_id);
                    }
                }
        }else{
            $view = generalOperations::viewsSelectPostCount($post_id);
        }
    }
}
```

final answer